# Django on heroku serves static but HTML templates don't not use them.

Tags: css, django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am making a small recipe website for a friend of mine in django. Currently, I am in the process of deploying it to Heroku. I am using Amazon S3 for static content.

Here is the website: https://chiryaroti.herokuapp.com/

It seems S3 itself is working fine as it downloads css, and js. But, when I "inspect elements" in firebug, it says no style attached.

Why is not HTML making use of the css stylesheets ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting insecure resources(http) in a secure page(https), those resources are blocked by browsers.

You should use protocol-relative paths.

e.g.

```
<link href="//chiryaroti.s3.amazonaws.com/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Just changed that, and the the css are working fine. Thanks a lot. Have a great night !!